# Format String Issue

Tags: vb.net, methods, split

I am having so much trouble with this homework assignment. Please help if you can.

The problem is below:

> Suppose a text file "degrees.txt" contains the number of bachelor degrees conferred in 1981 and 2011 in certain fields of study. The file looks like the following:
>
> > Field of Study,1981,2011
> >     Business,200521,311574
> >     Computer and Info. Science,15121,54111
> >     Education,105074,105451
> >     Engineering,63642,64906
> >     Social Sciences and History,100513,156892
>
> Write a program that provides the user with the following options. Your code should work for ANY text file  as long as it follows the same format:
>
> > field name1, number of degrees in 1981, number of degrees in 2011
> >     field name2, number of degrees in 1981, number of degrees in 2011
> >     ...
>
> The number of fields in the text file is unknown.
>
> a) Display the content of the text file in a formatted table."

When I write my program, it's not aligned correctly. My code is below:

```
Public Class frmDegrees
    Dim degrees() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Degrees.txt")

    Private Sub btnDegrees_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDegrees.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strfmt As String = "{0,-60}{1,10}{2,10}"
        Dim fields(3) As String

        For i = 0 To degrees.Count - 1
            fields = Split(degrees(i), ",")
            lstDegrees.Items.Add(String.Format(strfmt, fields(0), fields(1), fields(2)))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Might also help to describe what you mean by "not aligned correctly"...

Comment: @DavidZemens Apparently all the OP needs is to set a monospace font for `lstDegrees`.

Comment: Use a listview instead of a listbox as the "formatted table" and they will line up perfectly

Comment: Your title did not match your problem. I renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `DataGridView` to your form, and insert your table into it. The `DataGridView` would have a property called `AutoSizeColumnsMode` that you could set to `AllCells`. And, if you want to align the numbers to the right you can set the `Alignment` property of a column's `DefaultCellStyle` to `MiddleRight`.

```
Dim degrees() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Degrees.txt")

DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() 'Remove any data the was previously populated.
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear() 'Remove any data the was previously populated.
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

For i = 0 To degrees.Count - 1
    If i = 0 Then 'if it's the first line in the file, create columns/headers.
        For Each s as String In degrees(i).Split(",")
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(s, s)
        Next
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    Else 'otherwise just add a new row.
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(degrees(i).Split(","))
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the formatting assignment done - your problem is with the ListBox - a horrible invention IMO.

Adam's answer is probably best if you what to see the data in a grid - that would be my choice for a UI.

Here is some code that displays the formatted string but it depends on a fixed width font being used. Instead of debug.print you could send the output to a TextBox with the multiline property set. This code uses a data type of List(of String), not a ListBox.

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim sData As String = "Field of Study,1981,2011|"  ' use | to delimit rows
        sData &= "  Business,200521,311574|"
        sData &= "  Computer and Info. Science,15121,54111|"
        sData &= "  Education,105074,105451|"
        sData &= "  Engineering,63642,64906|"
        sData &= "  Social Sciences and History,100513,156892"
        Dim strfmt As String = "{0,-60}{1,10}{2,10}"
        Dim lstData As New List(Of String)

        Dim aData() As String = sData.Split("|") ' build array of rows
        Dim aRow() As String
        For Each s In aData
            aRow = s.Split(",") ' split into fields
            'Debug.Print(String.Format(strfmt, aRow)) ' aRow is an array
            'Debug.Print(String.Format(strfmt, aRow(0), aRow(1), aRow(2))) ' same as above with individual argments
            lstData.Add(String.Format(strfmt, aRow))
        Next
        Debug.Print(String.Join(vbNewLine, lstData))
        Stop
    End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like I just needed to change my font to a fixed font. It's lining up perfectly now. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you all for your help. Silly me